# how to use separator param of print in swift2

Tags: swift

Sorry for newbee question.

I really do not know how to use separator param in print

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var strs = ["abc","def"]

print(str)
print(strs, separator: ",", terminator: "")
print(str, separator: ",", terminator: "\n")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` accepts its arguments separately, so you can do this:

```
print("abc", "def", separator: ",")
```

But you have an array of strings, so you should do this:

```
print(strs.joinWithSeparator(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("rob" ,"mark" , "hanna" , separator:"$") // prints rob$mark$hanna
```

To use separator we need to pass multiple string inside print function.